# Cannot communicate between controllers in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to develop a demo app using JavaFX where I have 2 controllers MainController and AddUserController, each of them has its own .fxml file, main.fxml contains table that displays the list of users, and a button that opens the window for adding user with some fields. So the list of users is contained in a in-memory DB.

So when adding an user the table isn't filled with the list.

MainController.java

```
public void setTestUser(){
    List<Users> users = new ArrayList();
    Users user = new Users();
    user.setName("Name");
    user.setSurname("Surname");
    users.add(user);
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Users, String>("name"));
    surname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Users, String>("surname"));
    usersTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(users));
}
```

AddUserController.java

```
private void handleAddUser(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/main.fxml").openStream());
    MainController mainController = fxmlLoader.getController();

    Users user = new Users();
    user.setName(name.getText());
    user.setSurname(surname.getText());
    user.setDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth.getValue().toString());

    usersService.add(user);

    mainController.populateUsersTable();
}
```

After adding the user the table isn't updated, but if I try to `usersTable.getItems();` the list is there, what's the problem so far?

// UPDATE:

Trying to execute this from MainController.java and it is working OK

```
public void setTestUser(){
        List<Users> users = new ArrayList();
        Users user = new Users();
        user.setName("Name");
        user.setSurname("Surname");
        users.add(user);
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Users, String>("name"));
        surname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Users, String>("surname"));
        usersTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(users));
    }
```

Comment: The GUI doesn't refresh?

Comment: Your code is incomplete and it is absolutely inclear what is called from where.

Comment: Besides, I am a bit surprised that the main controller is initialized whenever a new user is added… normally you do that just once.

Comment: And a class which handles one user should be named `User` and not `Users`. That creates confusion on the reader's side.

Comment: One thing that seems suspicious: the result of loading the fxml file doesn't seem to be used in the `handleAddUser` method. Are you only loading the fxml to get access to a controller instance? Also unrelated to your problem: I wouldn't open a `InputStream` for the `URL`. `FXMLLoader` can do this itself. Instead use the `URL` directly which allows you to reference resources relative to the fxml document (fxml url is unavailable for a stream): `fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/main.fxml"));`

Comment: @glglgl, think the Entity can be renamed any time, that's not the root problem. I can provide more code if it is needed.

Comment: @fabian, let me try this

Comment: @fabian, in that case the reference to MainController will be null

Comment: But why do you load a fxml just to "throw away the loaded". Usually you'd do: `Parent fxmlRoot = load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/main.fxml")); paneToAddTo.getChildren().add(fxmlRoot);` or alternatively use it in a `Scene`...

Comment: @fabian is correct in the main point of his comment. You load a *new copy* of the UI defined by main.fxml, and get the controller associated with that new copy. You never display that new copy of the UI, so when you update it via its controller, you are updating something that is not displayed and you cannot possibly see the result. You want to get the controller when you load *and display* the UI. As an aside, use `fxmlLoader.setLocation(url); fxmlLoader.load();`, not `fxmlLoader.load(url);`- the latter is a static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason might be that you create a new controller on a new pane each time you handle an "add user" event. This is plainly wrong, as changes to it don't affect the pane which is actually displayed.

Instead, you should get the controller when you load your pane, store it somewhere and refer to it whenever you need it.

```
FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(
                getClass().getResource(screen.getFile()),
                resources);
Parent loadScreen = myLoader.load();
XYController myScreenController = myLoader.getController();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works. And BTW, there was not a reason to down vote, when someone doesn't write or ask as you want just ask for more info. Just an advice, don't take it too personal.

Comment: @Denees Glad I could help. Well, indeed I asked and at the end I had to guess. Obviously I guessed right, but it was pure coincidence…